# TFS 2012 commit to recognize removed files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, tfs

I inherited a project that was a disaster of duplicate files that had copy of default.aspx.cs etc. I removed tons of garbage from this project and i want to commit a clean version of the project.  When i go to pending changes though i don't see how it can detect that those files are no longer there.

I am new to TFS and using Team Foundation Server 2012. What is the best approach to making this commit so that it recognizes that all those files where deleted? Using visual studio 2012 express.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a local workspace (the default in TFS 2012), you should be able to just map the Source Control folder to a local folder, and it should pick up any pending deletes.  You may have to "promote" them to Pending Changes in the Team Explorer.

[image]

Comment: Do they become listed in the pending changes section?

Comment: They are in the Pending Changes window, but under the Excluded Changes section by default; until you promote them.